# Updating boolean value fails because Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to change a boolean field from false to true when the user presses a button, however when I execute the code I get this error:

```
 Call to a member function update() on null
```

This is my migration:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('abteilung_name')->nullable()
            $table->boolean('isActive')->default(false);
            

        });
    }
```

I shortened it and the column I talk about is the `isActive`

Here is my controller code:

```
public function activate(Post $post, Request $request) {

        $postID = $request->id;

        $post = Post::find($postID);

        $post->update(['isActive' => 1]);


        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Anzeige veröffentlicht');
    }
```

Here is the blade code of the button for the user:

```
 <form method="post" action="{{ route('activate', $post->id) }}">
                                    @csrf
                                <button type="submit" class="text-white px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                bg-gradient-to-r from-green-400 to-blue-500 float-right shadow transition
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100">Anzeige genehmigen
                                </button>
                                </form>
```

In the database the isActive is currently saved as "0" (zero), I assume that's the laravel way of false since it is default false. I also tried this:

```
$post->update(['isActive' => true]);
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like you're already using route model binding to get the post i.e. the `Post $post` parameter of the method, why are you trying to load it again? You don't appear to be submitting an input named `id` so `$request->id` is going to be `null`.

Comment: It's not a question that needs answering, as it's unlikely to be reproduced by anyone else. It should be removed.

Comment: @miken32 oh shit okay. should I delete it? I couldn't post answers yesterday so I tried now just to be sure and it worked. I can delete it of course! Or should I delete the whole post?

Comment: The idea isn't just to help you solve the problem, it's also to help future visitors. The chances someone else is going to make the same errors together, and then find this answer, are pretty small. I would recommend deleting it (but you're welcome to do what you like with your question, of course.)

Comment: @miken32 nah you are right. I just thought the error message I got is rather specific, but since it doesn't even appear because of my goal I will delete. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that I already have the post model in the method with `Post $posts` so I can simply do it like this:

```
$post->update(['isActive' => 1]);
```

This way I have less code and I don't need to search for the post with the specific ID since it is already identified through the argument in the method